# Using SVN is it possible to obtain a repository subset as individual repository?

Tags: svn

I checked out the whole repository, but need only the `trunk` directory. Do I need to do a new checkout, or can I in someway take the `trunk` directory and use this as the repository, ignoring/removing the parent directory?

My current checkout has local svn-ignored changes applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Every folder in the working copy knows where it comes from in the repositorythanks to its .svn subdirectory.

Comment: Note that this will change in SVN 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `trunk` directory as your repository directly. If you don't want your parent directory, either just move your trunk directory to another place in your filesystem, or better yet, only checkout the `trunk` folder next time.

Answer (score 1):

In Subversion, each subdirectory has its own `.svn` folder, and keeps track of its own revisions and its own place in the repository.  You should be able to take the `trunk` folder and move it elsewhere and treat it as a working copy of its own, without issues.